# Exec two "while" functions in one script

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, while-loop

Im trying to to write a PHP code/script where two 'while' functions should be executed. I dont know if this is the correct method, but I'm not aware of anything else.

here's the complete code:

```
<div class="events">
<div class="eventhead">Log</div>

<?
include_once 'dbcon.php';
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM event_log ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10";
$rs2 = mysql_query($sql2);

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2)) {
do {
    $id = $row2['id'];
    $date = $row2['date'];
    $user = $row2['user'];
    $action = $row2['action'];
    $dept = $row2['dept'];
    $desc = $row2['desc'];


if ($dept == "Client") {
        $dsql = mysql_query("SELECT * AS title FROM clients WHERE cl_name LIKE '%$desc%'");
    } else if ($dept == "Device") {
        $dsql = mysql_query("SELECT * AS title FROM devices WHERE dev_id LIKE '%$desc%'");
    };

$query = mysql_query($dsql) or die (mysql_error());
while($dq = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
do {
    $did = $dq['id'];
    $title = $dq['title'];

?>
<p>• <?= $date ?> | User <?= $user ?> <?= $action ?> <?=$dept ?> - <?= $desc ?>.</p><br />
<p><?= $title ?></p>
<? } while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2)); ?>
<? } while($dq = mysql_fetch_array($query)); ?>
<? } ?>
<? } ?>

</div>
```

The line

```
<p>• <?= $date ?> | User <?= $user ?> <?= $action ?> <?=$dept ?> - <?= $desc ?>.</p><br />
```

works if i exclude this part of the code:

```
if ($dept == "Client") {
        $dsql = mysql_query("SELECT * AS title FROM clients WHERE cl_name LIKE '%$desc%'");
    } else if ($dept == "Device") {
        $dsql = mysql_query("SELECT * AS title FROM devices WHERE dev_id LIKE '%$desc%'");
    };

$query = mysql_query($dsql) or die (mysql_error());
while($dq = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
do {
    $did = $dq['id'];
    $title = $dq['title'];
```

The main reason I want to include that part is that the  results should be a hyperlink that refers to the ID of the client who's name is displayed there!

Let me explain it like this. If this script is executed in the browser without the faulty part of the script, it returns this:

**► 2013-08-29 18:19:19 | User demo changed Client - Myclient.**

where the database ID of **myclient** should retrieved and the hyperlink "client.php?id=..." should be created.

So, the problem comes in when running the second while function, i presume... but how else can I query another DB Table to get the ID and Name if the client to create the hyperlink??

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You may be able to use the `JOIN` statement or `UNION` in your query. Read up on both of those.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra ;

```
if ($dept == "Client") {
    $dsql = mysql_query("SELECT * AS title FROM clients WHERE cl_name LIKE '%$desc%'");
} else if ($dept == "Device") {
    $dsql = mysql_query("SELECT * AS title FROM devices WHERE dev_id LIKE '%$desc%'");
};
```

That last ; shouldn't be there

You need an extra } in the following line

```
<? } while($dq = mysql_fetch_array($query)); ?>
```

should be

```
<? }} while($dq = mysql_fetch_array($query)); ?>
```

and then take the last

```
<? } ?>
```

line out.

I haven't looked at the logic in depth although it looks like it would be easier just to do an inner join using a stored procedure but at least this will get you the syntax lined up properly.

Also, your php tagging style

```
<? ?>
```

on each line at the end isn't required and just using

```
<?php
```

on the first line and

```
?>
```

on the last would make it easier to read.